# Patch 9767 v2 error - most error like -> Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected! Assume -R? [n]

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches, supee-9767

How can I solve the below error,

> Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
>   Apply anyway? [n]
>   Skipping patch.

**==> What is mean exactly? How to solve?**

```
[abcd@12345 public_html]$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v2-2017-07-11-11-04-56.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php.rej
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
5 out of 5 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 88.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 106.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 601.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6.1.1-1.6.0.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php.rej
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 119.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml.rej
The next patch would create the file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/head-simple.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 37 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 38 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml.rej
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1281 (offset -4 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv.rej
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv.rej
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv.rej
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 417 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 964 (offset -15 lines).
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 268 (offset -5 lines).
The next patch would create the file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file js/varien/payment.js
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file js/varien/payment.js.rej
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js.rej
[abcd@12345 public_html]$
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at above history it looks like You already Applier `9767 v1`

Revert `9767 V1` and then again apply `9767 V2`

first, download `9767 v1` patch from Magento

For reverting `9767 V1` fire below command

```
sh filename(9767 filename).sh -R
```

after that apply `9767 V2`

For more info for reverting patch follow below URL http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#revert

Comment: okay. i have few doubts. what is mean reverting. and after apply patch 9767 v2 is any change required for 9767 v1

Comment: @zus There are some issues in 9767 v1 patch so magento introduce V2 patch so you already applied V1 patch so you need to revert v1 and need to apply V2

Comment: I have faced error, i can't successfully reverted . how can solve this. https://justpaste.it/1e9pn

Comment: You have manually change those files please revert those files with magento default and check

Comment: yes, i replaced by magento default -> Mage_Adminhtml.csv, still i am getting error? the error -> saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv.rej . there is no file like this.